# How to make the home slider fit exactly to all the screens

Tags: html, css, web, fullscreen

I want my home slider to fit exactly to any screen size(full screen).

Can anyone help me out with that.

Website link : [click for the website](http://www.testing.wi2wi.com/)

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and then create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can set your height and width in viewport which is `height:100vh` and `width:100vw`.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, But im sorry, i couldnot find where the viewport is. Can you please tell me detailedly where to set the height and width.

Comment: Set `height:100vh` and `width:100vw.` to the section that you want keep in the full screen.  Viewport value is a value like pixel but it calculate the value from the screen size. You can see more details here: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/